# Issues with angular $watch and retrieving data from database

Tags: model-view-controller, angularjs, controller

I'm a novice programming trying to put together a web application with Angular, node.js, and the graph database neo4j.

I would like to load content from my database dynamically based on the user selecting (or rejecting) terms (clicking buttons). Every time a button is clicked the relevant term is added to an array (either exclude or include). The idea is a new call to the database would be made each time a new term is selected.

I'm stuck right now on how to go about making calls to the database to retrieve the content. I'm trying to watch the arrays for changes using $watch. Something is going wrong and I'm having issues troubleshooting the problem.

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).    
controller('content',function($scope,$http, queryTerms, $watch){


    //watch arrays of terms for changes and fetch results based on what is selected
    $watch(function() { return angular.toJson( [ queryTerms.includedTerms, queryTerms.excludedTerms ] ) },
        function() {
            $http({
                method:'get',
                url:'/query/getContent',   
                params: {includeTerms:queryTerms.includedTerms , excludeTerms:queryTerms.excludedTerms}

            }).
            success(function(data){
                    //feed content data to display for viewing

            }).
            error(function(data){
                    $scope.test = "Error :("

            });
        });

});
```

I'm getting the following error when I use $watch:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $watchProvider <- $watch
```

Is this a terrible stupid way to go about this in general? Any advice would be greatly appreciated- I'm learning as I'm going and so far the advice I've gotten on here has be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: $watch's provider is $scope. you don't need to declare $watch as a dependency, only $scope.

Comment: Thanks for the information hunt- I suppose this is in the docs and that I didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$scope.$watch` instead.

```
controller('content', function ($scope, $http, queryTerms) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return angular.toJson([queryTerms.includedTerms, queryTerms.excludedTerms])
    },...
```